# Rails 3.1 on heroku run rake db:migrate does not happen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Rails 3.1

I have a heroku app made with the following command

```
heroku create app_name --stack cedar
```

I did

```
git add .
git commit -a -m "message"
git push heroku master
```

I have this in my gemfile

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

When I run

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
me@mine ~/projects/app_name
$
```

I get the running line but nothing happens. It just goes back to the $, waiting for a new command. I do not get any error messages. I have about 10 migration files in my git repo.

Funny thing is that it worked a few days ago. So I thought it might be something wrong with the heroku app. I deleted it, made a new cedar stack and pushed the repo. Same thing happened.

**Update**

This is in my .gitignore

```
.bundle
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
tmp/
.sass-cache/
```

I tried to delete the /db/schema.rb file from the local repo and committed and pushed

I tried

```
$ heroku pg:reset SHARED_DATABASE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you remember to run `bundle install` and then commit `Gemfile.lock` to your repository?

Comment: Did you already `db:push` a development database that has the `schema_migrations` table and migrations in there already?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Heroku has sometimes issues with migrations:

If you have this or a similar problem do this

```
heroku run bash --app appname
rake db:migrate
```